# How To Automate (Provide Answers) To Ubuntu Installer When Booting From NetBoot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, pxe, syslinux

I am trying to understand how to provide answers to the Ubuntu Server 20.04 network boot menu so that I can proceed to the next phase.

I am using Sys/PXE Linux and TFTP (tftpd-hpa) to achieve network boot. Here is my config:

```
LABEL ubsrv2004
    MENU LABEL Ubuntu Server 20.04
    KERNEL oses/ub2004/casper/vmlinuz
        append initrd=oses/ub2004/casper/initrd
```

Once the OS boots I get prompted with the following questions[image: Boot Sample]

*I have no interest in automating beyond this point just up to here*

Answer (score 0):

Your append line lacks of several parameters i.e. how the client is going to get its IP
then Debian installer asks the related questions in interactive mode.

You can see the rest of parameters by looking at Serva's page

[https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html)